# Is it possible to change font family when a default is defined for the AppTheme?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am defining a default font family for my app in the App theme, as such:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/trade_gothic_ltstd</item>
</style>
```

However, for some widgets I'd like a different font family. Pretty normal, right? Well, setting `android:fontFamily` has no effect. It *always* still uses the default trade gothic font. If I remove the fontFamily from the AppTheme then magically all my fontFamily assignments start working.

To actually change the font away from the default, I have to create the style below, and apply it to any `TextView`, `EditText`, etc. as a `style=@style/KnockoutFont`.

```
<style name="KnockoutFont" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/knockout_htf49_liteweight</item>
</style>
```

Is this expected?

Comment: you posted your question and answer. What are trying to ask? If it's whether this is the right way to do it, then yes. You're right.

Comment: @JacobCelestine yes, basically wondering if that's the only way to do it. I can't always set a custom style for things, so it's not a foolproof method. It's also a bit of a sanity check that I'm not crazy, because I don't understand why setting a default font would cause fontFamily to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct. But if you're looking for an alternative, you could try applying a font programmatically in your code for the views you want like this:

```
//Setting typefaces - this will give stylish fonts
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/FONT_NAME.EXTENSION");
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Now since this is in program, it should override the default font set by the theme. I'm not sure but this should work. If you try it, please let me know.